# How to change the shape of Chips component in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

When I added `ChipGroup` and Chips to XML, first it gave me rendering issue which caused activity crash.
I solved it by changing the support library version in the gradle.app from `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'` to alpha02 & changed AppTheme to `"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"`.

**Now the issue is that in the design section of androidStudio shape of the chip is default i.e. rounded but on emulator & actual device it is diamond shaped.
I tried the `app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"` property but it did not gave the desired result.

How to change the shape of the chip to rounded/default?**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.our_team.OurTeamActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip4"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="One Choice"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip5"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Two Action"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip6"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Three Entry"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip7"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Four Filter"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />
        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 15):

In the `Chip` the default value of the corner is defined in the style by the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
<item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.Chip</item>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.Chip" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

Just remove in your layout `app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just add this line in both themes.xml.

```
<item name="chipCornerRadius">4dp</item>
```